# how to use lstat() to determine if hard link or not

Tags: c, linux, symlink, stat, hardlink

My OS is linux. I program in C. I know I can use the lstat() to recognize the soft link, i.e., use S_ISLNK(st.st_mode). But how can I recognize the link is a hard link? if the link is a hard link, it will be thought of as a regular file. However, I also want to distinguish the regular file from the hard link. Are there any ways to handle this case?

Comment: Surely if it is not a soft link then it should be a hard link?

Comment: A regular file *is* a hard link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But how can I recognize the link is hard link?

You can't.

A "hard link" isn't actually anything special.  It's just a directory entry that happens to point to the same data on disk as a directory entry somewhere else.  The *only* way to reliably identify hard links is to map *all* the paths on your filesystem to inodes, and then see which ones point to the same value.

Answer (score 4):

struct stat has st_nlink member for number of hard links. It is > 1, file is being stated in one of the hard links to actual file content.

```
struct stat {
    dev_t     st_dev;     /* ID of device containing file */
    ino_t     st_ino;     /* inode number */
    mode_t    st_mode;    /* protection */
    nlink_t   st_nlink;   /* number of hard links */
    uid_t     st_uid;     /* user ID of owner */
    gid_t     st_gid;     /* group ID of owner */
    dev_t     st_rdev;    /* device ID (if special file) */
    off_t     st_size;    /* total size, in bytes */
    blksize_t st_blksize; /* blocksize for file system I/O */
    blkcnt_t  st_blocks;  /* number of 512B blocks allocated */
    time_t    st_atime;   /* time of last access */
    time_t    st_mtime;   /* time of last modification */
    time_t    st_ctime;   /* time of last status change */
};
```

Here is sample program:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
    struct stat buf = {0};
    lstat("origfile", &buf);
    printf("number of hard links for origfile: %d\n", buf.st_nlink);
}
```

output:

```
$ touch origfile
$ ./a.out
number of hard links for origfile: 1
$ ln origfile hardlink1
$ ./a.out
number of hard links for origfile: 2
$ ln origfile hardlink2
$ ./a.out
number of hard links for origfile: 3
```