# How to tell a difference between a file and a hard link pointing to that file

Tags: c

I have a C program, that is supposed to check the whole filesystem for a hard links to a specific file, but when I run it, the program returns all hard links pointing to that file + the file itself.

I'm using system call `stat()` and then I extract `st_dev` and `st_ino` from struct stat. 
The problem seems to occur, because all hard links and the original file have those two parameters identical.

Can someone tell me, how can I set them apart?

Comment: A directory entry("filename") is a link to an inode. A second link to the same inode is also a file. The files do not differ, only in name, or the directory where they live.

Comment: you need `lstat()`, not `stat()`, and then your question becomes a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40564474/how-to-use-lstat-to-determine-if-hard-link-or-not

Comment: "the file itself" is a hard link to the underlying filesystem object that is the file.

Comment: What we all are trying to say is: There is no difference between "the file" and any hard link to it, because "the file" is already the first hard link.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I think I get it now. I had to return only the hard links to a specific file for this assignment. My approach was to search through the whole file-system, looking for files with the same inode number as the original file. That's why my program was returning the original file alongside "other" hard links to that file. Turns out, I only had to check cwd, not the entire system. That solved it for me.